# meta tag "viewport" content="width=device-width" not working

Tags: css, html, meta-tags, meta

The meta tag is not reacting to a mobile (iphone) viewport as it should.

i guess it's connected to the full width image in the top of the site.
any help and suggestion of how i can solve this?

you can see the site at this adress:
http://alonashkenazy.co.il/

Comment: Try `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` instead of two meta tags.

Comment: @Cheery allready have tried this, not working.

Answer (score 4):

This is not wrong, because using multiple meta tags with the same name is valid HTML:

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
```

But we don't know how search engines and other readers will interpret them. Either two meta tags will be concatenated or one of them will be ignored/overwritten.
To avoid possible problems I would recommend to use a single meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

P.S. For more mobile site usage get more info from [HTML5 Mobile Boilerplate template](https://github.com/h5bp/mobile-boilerplate/blob/master/index.html)